# @Value application.properties come with a null URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm having a pretty annoying problem with application.properties.

I have a Java 11 project with Spring boot working perfectly, I can get all values ​​normally using :

```
 @Value("${example}")
```

Except when I try to get this URL coming from properties. This url is passed and called in a RestTemplate, and it always comes null.

```
@Value("${url}")
private String url

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

restTemplate.postForObject(url,new HttpEntity<>(getBody(),getHeaders()), DTO.class);
```

By hovering the mouse over the (${"url"}, the http appears: saying it is capturing, but when it reaches the part of the code that goes through @RestTemplate, the value is null.

I put up a log.info(url) and on Springboot's climb it shows the correct value with the url, but when it goes through the code line: the value comes to null

If I go directly to the class:
private static String URL = "http:example.com" , the code runs fine.

My application.properties in folder of project/src/main/resources

```
 server.port=8088
 
 url=http://example.com
 
 spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
 spring.rabbitmq.username=user
 spring.rabbitmq.password=password
 spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitm.example.com
 spring.rabbitmq.template.exchange=test-sender
 spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.enabled=true
 spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.multiplier=2
```

My code:

```
package com.test;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Service
public class TestService {


    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;  //coming from properties is always null

    //private static String URL1 = "http.com.example"; //
    // this way works as static


    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(url);
    }

      public TestResponseServiceDTO getTest(){

       log.info(url)           // here also shows a correct url on the console
       System.out.println(url) // here also shows a correct url on the console
       // Even at this point in my code, the url comes from the line below and it comes null


       TestResponseServiceDTO response=restTemplate.postForObject(url, // Here the URL appears null
       new HttpEntity<>(getbody(),getHeaders()),TestResponseServiceDTO.class);

       return response;

       }
}
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Hi, please could you copy/paste the actual code, this is hard to help you with pseudo code.

Comment: Also add your configuration file.

Comment: Updated code and properties files

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the property in question as following, which is incorrect

```
@Value(${"url"})
private String url;
```

Try changing it to

```
@Value("${url}")
private String url;
```

Now if you've mentioned the url in the properties file and the above class is a bean managed by spring (annoated by component or service) then url won't be null unless you set it to null again later in the code prior using it in the rest template call.

**Another case:** Also, make sure that you should invoke the `getTest()` method from spring managed bean. So, you shouldn't be doing something like this.

```
TestService  testService = new TestService();
testService.getTest();
```

Comment: I'm sorry here in the example I put it wrong, but in Java it's correct as you mentioned, I'll edit the question ok?

Comment: Add full class code and also the properties file content.

Comment: Update this file.

Comment: Are you getting null too in the `@PostConstruct` sop stmt? I also want to see, how your're invoking the `getTest()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any issue in the code you have provided.

First thing we have to understand is if the value was not resolved  when application startup, application won't even start. Plus even you have mentioned that when you hover over `("${url}")` value is captured!

I can see you have print the value of `url` to console in your `PostConstruct` method. First thing what you can do check that.

Only reason I can think of is, value of `url` is changed at run time by mistake or on purpose. You can avoid this from happening by removing `@Data` annotation from your `TestService` class. I don't see an reason why would you need `@Data`, `@AllArgsConstructor`, `@NoArgsConstructor` annotations in the first place. Specially `@Data`, because it can introduce unnecessary mutability to your `TestService` class. You can use `@Getter` if you need to access private variables.

Comment: @Almight great! Check whether this will resolve your issue or not! If not, we'll look what else can be wrong here.